# Android changes to be made in Manifest working with different packages

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have two packages and within them are multiple activities. After seeing the replies in stackoverflow, i have made necessary changes in manifest file, still the apk doesnt runs.
Here is my sample manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xyz.user.login"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SucessRetrieveCredActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ResetPasswordMessageActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ResetPasswordActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.xyz.stylist.search.ServiceMap" >
    </activity>


    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I have to import import com.hairologie.user.login.R; in ServiceMap activity, still it doesnt works. Earlier when ServiceMap and other activities were in same package, it worked just fine.

Comment: Please, give the names of your 2 packages. As I see `com.xyz.user.login` is your main activity

Comment: I think the problem is not your manifest file. Since you moved some Activities from one package to another, something happened. Try to clean your project and refresh (to generate new `gen`). After you can try to restart Eclipse

Comment: What is your Package name? is it com.xyz.user.login or com.hairologie.user.login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xyz"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".user.login.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".user.login.SucessRetrieveCredActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".user.login.ResetPasswordMessageActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".user.login.ResetPasswordActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".stylist.search.ServiceMap" >
    </activity>


    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: I edited my answer, change your package name in common name for your all activities. I tried it works now

Answer (score 0):

Write 
  `android:name="com.yourpackage.activityName"` in ManifestFile instead of 
`android:name = ".ActivityName"` 
it will solve the issue.

Comment: what shud be the parent tag of package?

Answer (score 0):

Change your package name in manifest to com.xyz

declare all the activities like 
android:name=".stylist.search.ServiceMap"

android:name=".user.login.SplashActivity"

After that clean and build your project and run